# Counting traffic to destination MAC address using ebtables/iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, traffic, mac-address

I would like to be able to count the number of bytes going to a given MAC address using `iptables` or `ebtables` or some other linux utility. I have tried looking at the byte counts in `ebtables` but they are always 0, am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by getting the IP address associated with each MAC address from `arp` and adding an accounting rule in `iptables` to count download traffic for that IP address.

Answer (score 1):

IPTables supports [traffic accounting](http://wiki.openvz.org/Traffic_accounting_with_iptables).  You should just be able to setup an IPtables rule matching the mac address you are interested in, then look at it's counters to see what kind of traffic it's pushing.  Note that you can't use this to look at traffic for other machines on the LAN, it will only be for traffic to or from the machine it's running on.

Comment: I'm running the machine as a firewall so it will have packets destined for other MAC addresses, but IPtables only has a source MAC address option, not a destination one.

Comment: Do you need this to be command line based? http://unix4lyfe.org/darkstat/ will do this all for you, and works very very nicely when run on a firewall.

Comment: Unfortunately it does need to be command line based.